# Can a PyQt4 QObject be queried to determine if the underlying C++ instance has been destroyed?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

The [destroyed()](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qobject.html#destroyed) signal can be trapped for a QObject, but I would like to simply test if the Python object still references a valid C++ Qt object. Is there a method for doing so directly?

Comment: There is no easier possibility in C++ Qt than catching the `destroyed()` signal, so i doubt this is possible with PyQt.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you import the sip module you can call its .isdeleted function.

```
import sip
from PyQt4.QtCore import QObject

q = QObject()
sip.isdeleted(q)
False

sip.delete(q)
q
<PyQt4.QtCore.QObject object at 0x017CCA98>

q.isdeleted(q)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: underlying C/C++ object has been deleted
```

Comment: is it possible without sip (or shiboken)?

Comment: I have found that importing sip from PyQt works better in some cases. Done as `from PyQt5 import sip`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [WeakRef](http://docs.python.org/library/weakref.html) class in the Python standard library. It would look something like:

```
import weakref

q = QObject()
w = weakref.ref(q)

if w() is not None: # Remember the parentheses!
    print('The QObject is still alive.')
else:
    print('Looks like the QObject died.')
```

Comment: The question is about the Qt object, not the Python object. Even if this might happen to work by a mere accident, but it's not the way to do it. And it's more work than listening for the signal.

Comment: @Rush: He asked "I would like to simply test if a Python reference is still valid". So that is exactly what this does.

Comment: Sorry, that quote is unclear. I am asking about the underlying C++ object. I'll fix the question.