# PyQt: RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object has been deleted

Tags: garbage-collection, pyqt, pyqt4, qobject, qmainwindow

If I run this code:

```
    #!/usr/local/bin/    python3

import sys 
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *


class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.button1 = QPushButton("1")
        self.button2 = QPushButton("2")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.button1)
        self.button1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.setCentralWidget(self.button2))
        self.button2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.setCentralWidget(self.button1))
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

...I get this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <lambda>
    self.button2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.setCentralWidget(self.button1))
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QPushButton has been deleted
```

I do not understand why the object is being deleted. Window should maintain a reference to it.
I have thoroughly investigated these posts:
[Understanding the “underlying C/C++ object has been deleted” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002895/understanding-the-underlying-c-c-object-has-been-deleted-error)
[Can a PyQt4 QObject be queried to determine if the underlying C++ instance has been destroyed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122451/can-a-pyqt4-qobject-be-queried-to-determine-if-the-underlying-c-instance-has-b?rq=1)

Why is the button being deleted?

Comment: I was having a similar problem with a subclass of QWidget, and it turned out the problem was that I had forgotten to call QWidget's `__init__` at the start of my `__init__`. Tricksy.

Comment: In our case, calling `a.call_some_parent_method()`, where `a = QObjectA(parent=QObjectB())`, raised a `RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QObjectA has been deleted`. However, the actual cause turned out to be that the wrapped object of type `QObjectB` had been deleted (not the `QObjectA` mentioned in the error message). Solution was to keep a reference to the `QObjectB` as well: `b = QObjectB(); a = QObjectA(parent=b)` (using Python 2.7, PyQt5)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40053635

Comment: In my case, attributes of a `QWidget` instance were getting deleted. It turned out that I only saved the `QWidget` instance to a local variable, so the garbage collector started deleting its attributes as soon as the variable went out of scope. The problem was solved by keeping a permanent reference to the `QWidget` instance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This answer to this question is as found here:
[Python PySide (Internal c++ Object Already Deleted)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339062/python-pyside-internal-c-object-already-deleted)

Apparently, assigning one widget to QMainWindow using setCentralWidget and then assigning another widget with setCentralWidget will cause the underlying c++ QWidget to be deleted, even though I have an object that maintains reference to it.

> Note: QMainWindow takes ownership of the widget pointer and deletes it at the appropriate time.

Answer (score 4):

This problem also occurs in PyQT5 when you run a continuous thread and close the mainwindow/dialog without closing thread first but in background the thread is processing. When you again open the window the second thread generated and delete the pre-existed widgets. You need to exit the thread first before re-run it. You can exit the thread by put the check on visibility of any widget in the mainwindow/dialog

```
            **if self.widget.isVisible() == False:
                break**
```

Comment: Thank you for this! You saved my day! I was getting a RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object Signals has been deleted. I put all my signals in a class. I had a thread in a while(1) loop constantly check a peripheral, in my design it should always run. But I implemented a log-in screen which would destroy and respawn the main GUI when logging out and loggin back in, so this error would happen after a log out and log back in.

Answer (score 3):

Brain's answer explains the problem perfectly. [This Link](http://enki-editor.org/2014/08/23/Pyqt_mem_mgmt.html) explain things in more detail.

My solution to this problem was to set the widgets as attributes of the object (e.g. simply using `self.label = ...` instead of `label = ...` in your class methods). You might want to do the same for any layouts attached to the widget.

This way you create a copy of the widget so that when C++ memory cleanup occurs, you still have a reference to the widget.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

In another case, the solution was to add all child objects to a detached layout first, and adding the layout to the parent layout as the last step.
That is:

```
    l = QGridLayout()
    l.addWidget(QLabel("child1"), 0, 0)
    l.addWidget(QLabel("child2"), 0, 1)
    ...
    parentLayout.addLayout(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

wxPython & PyPubSub:

For those who had the same error with wxPython and PyPubSub, look for the solution at:

[Defining a wx.Panel destructor in wxpython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26114034/defining-a-wx-panel-destructor-in-wxpython/73972953#73972953)

and the **nonzero**() method.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).