# wxPython check if the c++ part is deleted

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am working on a project where a function is throwing a `wx.pyDeadObject Error` because of a delayed task.

I've read that in wx [you can check if the c++ object still exsists by running `if self:`](http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/is-there-a-method-to-test-if-an-wx-object-exists-td2356531.html), however this no longer works in wxPython 3.0.2. using wx 3.

I've modified the function to the following:

```
def SetData(self, delayedResult):
    if not self or not self.list:
        return
    data = []
    torrents = delayedResult.get()

    for torrent in torrents:
        data.append((torrent.infohash, [torrent.name], torrent, ThumbnailListItemNoTorrent))

    self_exist = True
    list_exists = True

    if not self:
        self_exist = False
    if not self.list:
        list_exists = False

    try:
        self.list.SetData(data)
        self.list.SetupScrolling()
    except wx.PyDeadObjectError:
        print "Self existed: %s and self.list existed: %s" % (self_exist, list_exists)
```

It already passes the first if statement, but since the `delayedResutlt.get()` is blocking I added the additional try except (I also tried duplicating that if statement at the start of the function, but that didn't work).

When running one of the unit tests I got `Self existed: True and self.list existed: True` which confirmed my suspicions. The [documentation of 3.0.3](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/Window.html#Window.__nonzero__) says this should be present.

**How can you test if the c++ part of a wx object has been deleted in wxPython?**

Comment: Had the same question for the old wx, turns out the answer's the same. I couldnt write an almost duplicate, so generalized this question to apply for old wx as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out that you first have to `wx.Yield()` after having called `Destroy()` or something alike, in contrast to wx 2.8. The events then get processed and destroyed.

**In all cases, using `bool(object)` will evaluate to `True` or `False` depending on if the object is still active.**

Answer (score 0):

To know if c++ object of a wxPython window still exists, you must use

```
self.__nonzero__()
```

A more detailed answer at:
[Defining a wx.Panel destructor in wxpython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26114034/defining-a-wx-panel-destructor-in-wxpython)

and also documentation from wxPython and the PyDeadObject error at:
https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/MigrationGuide.html