# wrapped C/C++ object of type DictModel has been deleted

Tags: python

I am getting the following error while trying to debug the code using Variable explorer in spyder.

RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type DictModel has been deleted

Please suggest me a way to solve it.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyQt: RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object has been deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914960/pyqt-runtimeerror-wrapped-c-c-object-has-been-deleted)

Comment: This is probably a bug in spyder.

Comment: So how to resolve it?