# PyQt5 : Wrapped c/c++ object has been deleted

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, fbs

I am trying to create my own graphicsitem with a circle and its label at the center.

```
class circle(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, radius=None, name=None, x=None, y=None, parent=None):
        super(circle, self).__init__(parent)
        self.radius = radius if radius else random.random()*500
        self.label = name if name else "cirA"
        self.x = x if x else random.randint(0, 900)
        self.y = y if y else random.randint(0, 600)
        # self.center = complex(self.x, self.y)

    def boundingRect(self):
        penWidth = 1.0
        return QRectF(-self.x - penWidth / 2, -self.y - penWidth / 2,
                      self.x + penWidth, self.y + penWidth)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter.drawEllipse(0, 0, self.radius, self.radius)
        painter.drawText(self.label)
```

Now in my main gui, a list of a circles is held as circleList and I am trying to add the circle item as

```py
for cir in self.circleList:
            self.painter.addItem(cir)
```

but this returns

```sh
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type circle has been deleted
```

help?

this should do the trick for the minimal reproduce able example

note: FBS is required and project should be started using

```sh
fbs startproject
```

the circle is also to be added along with the following

```py
from fbs_runtime.application_context.PyQt5 import ApplicationContext
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
class gui(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(gui, self).__init__(parent)
        self.painter = QGraphicsScene(10, 10, 900, 600)
        self.canvas = QGraphicsView(self.painter)
        mainLayout = QGridLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.canvas, 0, 0, 6, 2)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.circleList = []

    def drawCircle(self):
        pen = QPen(Qt.black, 2, Qt.SolidLine)
        self.painter.clear()
        for cir in self.circleList:
            self.painter.addItem(cir)
        self.painter.update()
        self.canvas.update()
        self.update()

    def newCircle(self, cir):
        self.circleList.append(cir)
        self.drawCircle()

    def addCircle(self):
        return self.newCircle(circle())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = ApplicationContext()
    test = gui()
    test.show()
    exit(app.app.exec_())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyQt: RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object has been deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914960/pyqt-runtimeerror-wrapped-c-c-object-has-been-deleted)

Comment: @mkam i believe it doesnt, i looked into it and i am not using QMainWindow.

Comment: But see the link in Ankit's answer, which explains a lot of what is probably happening: http://enki-editor.org/2014/08/23/Pyqt_mem_mgmt.html

Comment: @eyllanesc updated original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graphics View Framework does not need you to remove and add the items. In your case, when using clear(), you are removing the items from the scene and you are removing them from the memory, so circleList will have variables that no longer have allocated memory.

On the other hand if you want a custom QGraphicsItem that draws a circle and a text in the center then the boundingRect must have the size of the rectangle ex-inscribed to the circle.

Considering the above, the solution is as follows:

```py
class Circle(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, radius=None, name="", x=0, y=0, parent=None):
        super(Circle, self).__init__(parent)
        self.radius = radius or random.random() * 500
        self.label = name if name else "cirA"
        self.setPos(x or random.randint(0, 900), y or random.randint(0, 900))

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(0, 0, self.radius, self.radius)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter.drawEllipse(0, 0, self.radius, self.radius)
        painter.drawText(0, 0, self.radius, self.radius, Qt.AlignCenter, self.label)
```

```py
class Gui(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Gui, self).__init__(parent)
        self.painter = QGraphicsScene(10, 10, 900, 600)
        self.canvas = QGraphicsView(self.painter)
        mainLayout = QGridLayout(self)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.canvas)

    @property
    def circleList(self):
        return [item for item in self.painter.items() if isinstance(item, Circle)]

    def newCircle(self, cir):
        self.painter.addItem(cir)
        return cir

    def addCircle(self):
        return self.newCircle(Circle())
```

Comment: Thanks once again! My logic behind clearing the scene was if i were to rename a circle's label once its drawn by having the user select the circle, and then rename it, i would then just change its label from the circle list and then have the drawcircle function redraw it. But it seems now, i cant do that